# How to do a OR in HQL when there is no value with which we are comparing it gives this error java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, mysql, hql

**This is the sentence HQL**

```
    select r.response as response from  Responsemix as r right join r.idOptQuestion
    as opt  where opt.idQuestion=5 and opt.content='Other' or opt.content='Others' 
    order by r.response asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem with the **`or`** in this Hibernate query, apart from a possible logic issue with the order of precedence between OR and AND.

From your query text, we deduce that what you probably wanted is:

```
... where opt.idQuestion=5 and ( opt.content='Other' or opt.content='Others' )
```

I believe Hibernate will also allow you to write this as:

```
... where opt.idQuestion=5 and opt.content in ('Other','Others')
```

---

Are you saying that if you remove this portion: `"or opt.content='Others'"` from the query text, then the query works. But when you add that back in to the query, Hibernate is throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException ? *Sweeeeet.*